# How can I make a JQuery UI Dialog automatically scroll when new div is appended?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, autoscroll

I have a JQuery UI dialog popup that displays a form. By clicking add more button i can add new form into the JQuery UI dialog.

How can I make the JQuery UI dialog automatically scroll and show the user the new blank form when the add new button is clicked.

Div added

```
<div>
    <form id="1">
        <label class="dbright">DashBoard ID:</label><span class="dbleft"><select id="dashboard_id" class="dbSettingDD"><option>-------Select-------</option><option id="#dashboard">Inventory</option><option id="#dashboard2">Quality</option><option id="#dashboard3">Complaints</option></select><br></span>

        <label class="dbright">Filtering parameter:</label><span class="dbleft"><select id="filter_by"><option>-------Select-------</option></select><br></span>

        <label class="dbright">Y-Axis:</label><span class="dbleft"><select id="yAxis"><option>-------Select-------</option></select><br></span>

        <label class="dbright">Chart Tiltle:</label><span class="dbleft"><input type="text" id="title"><br></span>

        <label class="dbright">Chart Type:</label><span class="dbleft"><input type="text" id="chart_type"><br></span>

        <label class="dbright">Main Chart:</label><span class="dbleft"><input type="radio" name="mainchart" value="yes">Yes <input type="radio" name="mainchart" value="No">No<br></span>

    </form>
</div>
```

Dialog

```
$("#dbSetting_div").dialog({
    height: 315,
    width: 500,
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    buttons: {
        "Save": function () {},
        "Add More": function () {
            l_i++;
            formHtml = "<div>";
            formHtml += "<form id='" + l_i + "'>";
            formHtml += "<label class = 'dbright'>DashBoard ID: </label><span class = 'dbleft'><select id='dashboard_id' class='dbSettingDD'><option>-------Select-------</option>" + dropDownDashboardName + "</select></br></span>";
            formHtml += "<label class = 'dbright'>Filtering parameter: </label><span class = 'dbleft'><select id='filter_by'><option>-------Select-------</option></select></br></span>";
            formHtml += "<label class = 'dbright'>Y-Axis: </label><span class = 'dbleft'><select id='yAxis'><option>-------Select-------</option></select></br></span>";
            formHtml += "<label class = 'dbright'>Chart Tiltle: </label><span class = 'dbleft'><input type='text' id='title'/></br></span>";
            formHtml += "<label class = 'dbright'>Chart Type: </label><span class = 'dbleft'><input type='text' id='chart_type'/></br></span>";
            formHtml += "<label class = 'dbright'>Main Chart: </label><span class = 'dbleft'><input type='radio' name='mainchart' value='yes'/>Yes <input type='radio' name='mainchart' value='No'/>No</br></span>";
            formHtml += "</form>";
            formHtml += "</div>";
            $("#dbSetting_div").append("<p>" + formHtml + "</p>");
            console.log(scroll);
        }
    }
}).css("font-size", "12px");
```

Comment: Please provide complete code (incl. js responsible for "clicking add more button")

Comment: @matty updated the code with add dialog details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it, especially the adding of the form's new HTML.

First off, I would add the HTML to the Page, with a display of `none` and some sort of `template` ID, like so:

```
<div id="formTemplate" style="display: none;">
    <form id="1">
        <label class="dbright">DashBoard ID:</label><span class="dbleft"><select id="dashboard_id" class="dbSettingDD"><option>-------Select-------</option><option id="#dashboard">Inventory</option><option id="#dashboard2">Quality</option><option id="#dashboard3">Complaints</option></select><br></span>
        <label class="dbright">Filtering parameter:</label><span class="dbleft"><select id="filter_by"><option>-------Select-------</option></select><br></span>
        <label class="dbright">Y-Axis:</label><span class="dbleft"><select id="yAxis"><option>-------Select-------</option></select><br></span>
        <label class="dbright">Chart Tiltle:</label><span class="dbleft"><input type="text" id="title"><br></span>
        <label class="dbright">Chart Type:</label><span class="dbleft"><input type="text" id="chart_type"><br></span>
        <label class="dbright">Main Chart:</label><span class="dbleft"><input type="radio" name="mainchart" value="yes">Yes <input type="radio" name="mainchart" value="No">No<br></span>
    </form>
</div>
```

Then, I can use this in the `add method` to quickly clone the material i need, remove the display none, and paste new form in! Something like so:

```
$("#dbSetting_div").css("font-size", "12px").dialog({
    height: 315,
    width: 500,
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    buttons: {
        "Save": function () { /*    do work */ },
        "Add More": function () {
            $("#dbSetting_div").append($('<p />').append($('#formTemplate').clone().show()))
                .animate({ scrollTop: $('#dbSetting_div')[0].scrollHeight}, 500);
        }
    }
});
```

Within that, I use `.animate` to scroll dialog to bottom whenever a new form is added. You could also just go pure straight change and skip the animation like: `$("#dbSetting_div").scrollTop($('#dbSetting_div')[0].scrollHeight);`

Anyway, that should help ya get started. Let me know if you need more help. For now, check out the 


## Working Example